# Difference between INNER JOIN and LEFT SEMI JOIN

Tags: sql, hql, hive

What is the difference between an `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT SEMI JOIN`?

In the scenario below, why am I getting two different results?

The `INNER JOIN` result set is a lot larger. Can someone explain? I am trying to get the names within `table_1` that only appear in `table_2`.

```
SELECT name
FROM table_1 a
    INNER JOIN table_2 b ON a.name=b.name

SELECT name
FROM table_1 a
    LEFT SEMI JOIN table_2 b ON (a.name=b.name)
```

Comment: The inner join will achieve your goal.  I had never heard of a semi join until I saw this question.

Comment: The `left semi join` should be returning more rows than the `inner join`.

Comment: The `inner join` will return data only if there is a match between both tables. The `left join` will return data from the first table regardless if a matching record is found in the second table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff not necessarily, a `LEFT SEMI JOIN` will only return one row from the left, even if there are multiple matches in the right.  An `INNER JOIN` will return multiple rows if there are multiple matching on the right.

Comment: Ask google and you shall receive    http://sqlity.net/en/1348/a-join-a-day-the-left-semi-join/

Comment: @j03z that can't be correct.  If the purpose of the left hemi-join is 1) to return only the information in the left table (as others have said) and 2) to return rows from teh left table regardless of match (as I think you say) then that is just the original left table -- no join is necessary to accomplish that.  I think others must be correct that the left hemi-join 1) only returns columns from the left table, 2) only returns rows that have a match in the right table, and 3) will return a single row from the left for one or more matches.

Answer (score 192):

An `INNER JOIN` can return data from the columns from both tables, and can duplicate values of records on either side have more than one match.  A `LEFT SEMI JOIN` can only return columns from the left-hand table, and yields one of each record from the left-hand table where there is one or more matches in the right-hand table (regardless of the number of matches).  It's equivalent to (in standard SQL):

```
SELECT name
FROM table_1 a
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM table_2 b WHERE (a.name=b.name))
```

If there are *multiple* matching rows in the right-hand column, an `INNER JOIN` will return one row for each match on the right table, while a `LEFT SEMI JOIN` only returns the rows from the left table, regardless of the number of matching rows on the right side.  That's why you're seeing a different number of rows in your result.

> I am trying to get the names within table_1 that only appear in table_2.

Then a `LEFT SEMI JOIN` is the appropriate query to use.

Comment: Is there really such a thing as a `LEFT SEMI JOIN`? Isn't is just a `SEMI JOIN`? There's no sense to a `RIGHT SEMI JOIN`, is there?

Comment: In [Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins), yes.

Comment: great answer just what i was looking for. 
i would phrase the answer more accurately :"...an INNER JOIN will return one row for each matching **row of the right table**, while a LEFT SEMI JOIN...

Comment: The opposite of this is a LEFT ANTI JOIN that filters out the data from the right table in the left table according to a key. Thought I'd leave this nugget here for someone who might be looking!

Answer (score 116):

Suppose there are 2 tables TableA and TableB with only 2 columns (Id, Data) and following data:

**TableA:**

```
+----+---------+
| Id |  Data   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | DataA11 |
|  1 | DataA12 |
|  1 | DataA13 |
|  2 | DataA21 |
|  3 | DataA31 |
+----+---------+
```

**TableB:**

```
+----+---------+
| Id |  Data   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | DataB11 |
|  2 | DataB21 |
|  2 | DataB22 |
|  2 | DataB23 |
|  4 | DataB41 |
+----+---------+
```

**Inner Join** on column `Id` will return columns from both the tables and only the matching records:

```
.----.---------.----.---------.
| Id |  Data   | Id |  Data   |
:----+---------+----+---------:
|  1 | DataA11 |  1 | DataB11 |
:----+---------+----+---------:
|  1 | DataA12 |  1 | DataB11 |
:----+---------+----+---------:
|  1 | DataA13 |  1 | DataB11 |
:----+---------+----+---------:
|  2 | DataA21 |  2 | DataB21 |
:----+---------+----+---------:
|  2 | DataA21 |  2 | DataB22 |
:----+---------+----+---------:
|  2 | DataA21 |  2 | DataB23 |
'----'---------'----'---------'
```

**Left Join** (or Left Outer join) on column `Id` will return columns from both the tables and matching records with records from left table (Null values from right table):

```
.----.---------.----.---------.
| Id |  Data   | Id |  Data   |
:----+---------+----+---------:
|  1 | DataA11 |  1 | DataB11 |
:----+---------+----+---------:
|  1 | DataA12 |  1 | DataB11 |
:----+---------+----+---------:
|  1 | DataA13 |  1 | DataB11 |
:----+---------+----+---------:
|  2 | DataA21 |  2 | DataB21 |
:----+---------+----+---------:
|  2 | DataA21 |  2 | DataB22 |
:----+---------+----+---------:
|  2 | DataA21 |  2 | DataB23 |
:----+---------+----+---------:
|  3 | DataA31 |    |         |
'----'---------'----'---------'
```

**Right Join** (or Right Outer join) on column `Id` will return columns from both the tables and matching records with records from right table (Null values from left table):

```
┌────┬─────────┬────┬─────────┐
│ Id │  Data   │ Id │  Data   │
├────┼─────────┼────┼─────────┤
│  1 │ DataA11 │  1 │ DataB11 │
│  1 │ DataA12 │  1 │ DataB11 │
│  1 │ DataA13 │  1 │ DataB11 │
│  2 │ DataA21 │  2 │ DataB21 │
│  2 │ DataA21 │  2 │ DataB22 │
│  2 │ DataA21 │  2 │ DataB23 │
│    │         │  4 │ DataB41 │
└────┴─────────┴────┴─────────┘
```

**Full Outer Join** on column `Id` will return columns from both the tables and matching records with records from left table (Null values from right table) and records from right table (Null values from left table):

```
╔════╦═════════╦════╦═════════╗
║ Id ║  Data   ║ Id ║  Data   ║
╠════╬═════════╬════╬═════════╣
║  - ║         ║    ║         ║
║  1 ║ DataA11 ║  1 ║ DataB11 ║
║  1 ║ DataA12 ║  1 ║ DataB11 ║
║  1 ║ DataA13 ║  1 ║ DataB11 ║
║  2 ║ DataA21 ║  2 ║ DataB21 ║
║  2 ║ DataA21 ║  2 ║ DataB22 ║
║  2 ║ DataA21 ║  2 ║ DataB23 ║
║  3 ║ DataA31 ║    ║         ║
║    ║         ║  4 ║ DataB41 ║
╚════╩═════════╩════╩═════════╝
```

**Left Semi Join** on column `Id` will return columns only from left table and matching records only from left table:

```
┌────┬─────────┐
│ Id │  Data   │
├────┼─────────┤
│  1 │ DataA11 │
│  1 │ DataA12 │
│  1 │ DataA13 │
│  2 │ DataA21 │
└────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: I used to call this as "LEFT INNER Join".

Comment: DISTINCT of A.* from INNER JOIN result is equivalent to LEFT SEMI JOIN.

Comment: Distinct does not sound safe, suppose A contains two identical records.

Comment: Even if the result ends up being the same, using DISTINCT might have a more expensive plan compared to EXISTS

Answer (score 33):

Tried in Hive and got the below output

table1

> 1,wqe,chennai,india
>
> 2,stu,salem,india
>
> 3,mia,bangalore,india
>
> 4,yepie,newyork,USA

table2

> 1,wqe,chennai,india
>
> 2,stu,salem,india
>
> 3,mia,bangalore,india
>
> 5,chapie,Los angels,USA

Inner Join

> SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id);
>
> 1       wqe     chennai    india   1       wqe     chennai     india
>
> 2       stu     salem      india   2       stu     salem       india
>
> 3       mia     bangalore   india   3       mia     bangalore   india

Left Join

> SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id);
>
> 1       wqe     chennai    india   1       wqe     chennai     india
>
> 2       stu     salem      india   2       stu     salem       india
>
> 3       mia     bangalore   india   3       mia     bangalore   india
>
> 4       yepie   newyork    USA     NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL

Left Semi Join

> SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT SEMI JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id);
>
> 1       wqe     chennai   india
>
> 2       stu     salem     india
>
> 3       mia     bangalore   india
>
> note: Only records in left table are displayed whereas for Left Join both the table records displayed

Comment: You should really put some duplicate ids in the RHS table to see the full difference though - e.g. if you have two values with id 1 in table 2, you will get 2 rows in the result for them with INNER JOIN and only one with LEFT SEMI JOIN.

That shows that you can get a different number of rows returned, as well as only getting columns from the LHS table with the LSJ

Answer (score 4):

All above answers are correct. However in practice, it helps to associate the mental model of a `filter` when imagining LEFT SEMI JOIN.

The answer is a subset of rows from LEFT table, which have a match in RIGHT TABLE.

Answer (score 1):

Semi Joining `Left` with `Right` give you the rows that would have been kept in `Left` if you would join with `Right`

```
Left table: 
KEY:  1, 2, 3
VAL1: a, b, c

Right table: 
KEY:  2, 3, 4
VAL2: d, e, f

# Semi join: 
KEY:  2, 3
VAL1: b, c

# Actual inner join
KEY:  2, 3
VAL1: b, c
VAL2: d, e
```

Answer (score 1):

They are exactly the same unless two things happen:

1. There is/are duplicate records in the resulting table

In this case `inner join` brings in duplicates but `left semi` won't. So `distinct` of all rows in `inner join` = `left semi`

2. you want access to right table field names

In `inner join` we can get both left and right table in the result. But with `left semi` you only get left table. Why is that? Check this query:

```
SELECT name
FROM table_left left
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM table_right right WHERE (left.name=right.name))
```

In this query we cannot get access to fields in the inner table (table_right). And this is how `left semi` is implemented behind the scenes. It is an 'is in' operation.

If these two conditions wont't happen in your inner join then they are exactly the same. So it depends how you test it. And hence the confusion. A one line answer to the question would be

> One of them is not a join