# How to create a join expression from a list of join keys

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Experts, i have a list of columns which i need to use for a join expression while joining 2 Pyspark (1.6) dataframes (i can't hardcode this list in my join expression as it is part of common code).
I have these 2 dataframes-

```
>>> df.show()
+---------+---------+------+
|column1  |column2  |column3|
+---------+---------+------+
|     abcd|      xyz|   12A|
|    abcd1|      xyz|   12A|
+---------+---------+------+

>>> df1.show()
+---------+---------+------+
|column1  |column2  |column3|
+---------+---------+------+
|    abcd1|      xyz|   12A|
+---------+---------+------+
```

I am doing a left join and i only want entries which are present in "df" only.

Columns to join on-

```
joinCols = ['column1','column2','column3']

Join Expression-

>>> df.join(df1,joinCols,"left").show()
+---------+---------+------+
|column1  |column2  |column3|
+---------+---------+------+
|    abcd1|      xyz|   12A|
|     abcd|      xyz|   12A|
+---------+---------+------+
```

Now this join works file, no problem. But i am only looking for one entry in output.

```
|     abcd|      xyz|   12A|
```

Since join by default drops the columns from other dataframe "df1", i am not able to put condition on above join expression. I tried-

```
df.join(df1,joinCols,"left").filter(isnull(df1["column1"])).show()
```

This above errors out because it doesn't have a column in output to apply filter expression on. Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe spark 1.6 doesn't support it

Comment: just try this it will resolve your problem >>> df.join(df1,joinCols,"left").filter(isnull(df1.column1)).show()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use join with many conditions in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812537/how-to-use-join-with-many-conditions-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Spark v1.6, you will need to perform a [join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join) with `how="leftsemi"` option (Till Spark v2.1). From Spark v2.2, you have `left_semi`.

You can find a more detailed explanation about a left semi join at: [Difference between INNER JOIN and LEFT SEMI JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738784/difference-between-inner-join-and-left-semi-join)